# Implementing a control break and printing results

Tags: java, loops

I am learning about single-level control breaks. This program should produce a report that includes the day of the week, number of hours worked by each employee for each day, and the total hours worked each day.  All code up to the 'while' loop was given. I included the variable declarations for good measure.  I am responsible for completing the control break within the 'while' loop and printing the information stated above.  I have added some additional code, but am confused about the logic.  Assistance is appreciated. This is my first post so if I have broken any rules I apologize.

```
    final String HEAD1 = "WEEKLY HOURS WORKED";
    final String DAY_FOOTER = "             DAY TOTAL";   //spaces are on purpose
    final String SENTINEL = "done";
    double hoursWorked = 0;
    String hoursWorkedString = "";
    String dayOfWeek;
    double hoursTotal = 0;
    String prevDay = "";
    boolean done = false;

//Read first record
    dayOfWeek = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter day of week or done to quit: ");
    if (dayOfWeek.compareTo(SENTINEL) == 0)
        done = true;
        System.exit(0);
    else
    {
        hoursWorkedString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hours worked: ");
        hoursWorked = Integer.parseInt(hoursWorkedString);
        prevDay = dayOfWeek;
    }

    while(done == false)
    {
        //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO IMPLEMENT THE CONTROL BREAK
        if (dayOfWeek.compareTo(prevDay) != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(dayOfWeek + " " + hoursWorked);
            hoursTotal = 0
            prevDay = dayOfWeek;
        }
            System.out.println(dayOfWeek + " " + hoursWorked);
            hoursTotal = hoursTotal + hoursWorked;

         //ADDITIONAL WORK NEEDED HERE FOR dayChange() METHOD

    }
        System.out.println(DAY_FOOTER + hoursTotal);
        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: "single-level control break"? I've never heard that term.

Comment: Its from Programming Logic and Design, 7th Ed., J. Farrell. It is defined as a break in the logic of the program (in this case, pausing or detouring to output a count) that is based on the value of a single variable.

Comment: Reasons why you don't get answers: the problem you try to solve is really hard to understand (I've read your text twice and I still don't get what you have to do / how an answer would look like). You also posted quite a bit of code. Strip your question down to some small example that resembles your problem (e.g. the Ui is completely irrelevant) and describe the problem in simple english terms so people that studied computer science don't need to feel ashamed and need to ask what those terms are :)

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of control breaks as "breaks" in the key field data. The logic groups together like (key) values in a series of detail records. Iterating through the records and printing the individual "hours" is easy.  Getting a total at the end (the group of records matching by week) is fairly easy. But what if one wants the detail within the week, within the month, within the year? And, one wants the program to be efficient?  That's where control breaks come in handy.  Your text is starting you off with the easy "single level control break" and getting you ready for 3 or more level control breaks.

An entire programming language "RPG" (Report Generation Language) was built around the concept of control breaks.  Control breaks are best understood in the context of a "report", but can be useful in other situations.  Example: In a sense, an XML document is "a report", isn't it?  Control breaks, I have found, are closely related to the SQL "GROUP" clause.